# What is the difference between git config --list and git config --list --show-origin?

Tags: html, css, git, github, gitlab

What is the difference between `git config --list` and `git config --list --show-origin`
Please tell.

Comment: What's unclear in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---show-origin)? `--show-origin` adds the source of each entry to the output.

Comment: for reference : any git command has an extended documentation, which you can access running `git help <command>`. For example : you can get the doc content linked by RomainValeri by running `git help config`.

Comment: Perhaps the question should read "Why does `git config --show-origin` not work", which was my cause to get here.

Answer (score 2):

`git config --list` shows you all the variables, `--show-origin` also adds the source of the value.

For example, `--list` can show

```
core.excludesfile=/home/choroba/.gitignore_global
```

While `--show-origin` would also include

```
file:/home/choroba/.gitconfig    core.excludesfile=/home/choroba/.gitignore_global
```

I.e. the excludesfile is set to the ~/gitignore_global, and the actual setting happens in ~/.gitconfig.

Answer (score 0):

It perhaps can be confusing that

```
git config --show-origin
```

doesn't work, instead `--show-origin` must be used as a modifier together with the `--list` option like that:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

which then additionally lists the respective sources of the git configuration entries as expected.